# Convert quotation marks " " from binary in php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am working to convert text from binary to char while retrieving them from MYSQL database. The database uploads .txt files and converts to binary format while storing them in MediumBLOB data type. My problem is, when i am retrieving data it doesn't convert all the characters and hence displays garbage in place of them such as quotation marks. Can anyone please help.

I'm using the following query to convert in php:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Legislation_ID`, `Legislation_Name`, `Category_ID`, 
        CAST(`data` AS CHAR(1000000) CHARACTER SET utf8) As BLOBText
        FROM `legislations` WHERE `Legislation_ID` =5";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT `Legislation_ID`, `Legislation_Name`, `Category_ID`,
CONVERT(`data` USING utf8) FROM `legislations` WHERE `Legislation_ID` =5";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

```
$sql = "SELECT replace(CONVERT(`data` USING utf8),'\"','') as BLOBText FROM `legislations` WHERE `Legislation_ID` =5";
```

For more information about the `CONVERT()` [Read Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Comment: The above query gives the same result as of the Cast function. If there is a text for example; "Hello" it retrieves it as ?Hello? How should i fix this while retrieving?

Comment: Nope it gives an error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '','' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mariam.php on line 35

Comment: It was the PHP error because you have used  " for write query, Updated query check now

Comment: Its working but gives the same results as before. No conversion